# Mapstruct package private attributes

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

Is there any possibility to map package private attributes (without use of lombok). We successfully mapped package private classes to a DTO , but in order to successfully map the attributes we need them to have public getters and setters.

I console myself with the fact that the class is still package private, but that public before the attributes it's salt on an open wound :)

Thanks !
Alex.

Answer (score 1):

Currently MapStruct only support mapping from public fields / properties. There is an open [Feature Request](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1689) requesting functionality for package private / protected attributes.